# MQTT subscribing does not work properly in Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, mqtt, python-multithreading

I have code like below

```
    threads = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=Subscribe('username', "password", "topic", "host",port).start)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=Subscribe('username2', "password2", "topic2", "host",port).start)
    
    threads.append(t)
    threads.append(t1)
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

My topics send data in **every 5 minutes.**

When I use the code above,it does not work properly, sometimes it sends data sometimes it does not.

But when I use one topic without **thread** , it works fine and data is coming in every 5 minutes perfectly.

How can I solve this problem? I want to subscribe two topics **simultaneously**.

I am using **Paho** for **MQTT**

My subscribe class is

```
class Subscribe:

    def __init__(self, username, passowrd, topic, host, port):

        self.username = username
        self.password = passowrd
        self.topic = topic
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
       
      

    def start(self):
        self.mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="Python")
        self.connected = False
        self.mqtt_message = ""
        self.mqttc.username_pw_set(self.username, self.password)
        self.mqttc.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.mqttc.on_message = self.on_message
        self.mqttc.connect(self.host, self.port)
        self.mqttc.loop_forever()

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        """
        Fetch data when data coming to Broker
        """
        topic = message.topic
        m = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        print(m)

   


    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to broker", self.topic)
            self.mqttc.subscribe(self.topic)
            self.connected = True

        else:
            print("could not connect", self.topic)
```

Comment: Which mqtt library are you using? It's probably not built to handle multithreading and therefore you're causing data races and violating the assumptions of the library, which causes it to not work properly.

Comment: it is python-paho

Comment: I'd need more info to help. Can you show your Subscribe function? Do you create an instance of `paho.mqtt.client.Client()`? Where is it?

Comment: I edited  @LouisCloete check it out.

Comment: Can you try to just create the two Subscribe objects in a single thread? I want to eliminate threads as the cause. If it works in a single thread with 2 Clients then the threading was the issue, else the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I found I just gave two different client id , it worked.

Comment: Why do you need 2 separate clients at all? A single client can subscribe to any number of topics (or wildcards that match multiple topics) and handle all the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to give two different `client_id`s for the two instances of `Client` and it solved the issue.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. You can still check if it is necessary to create 2 threads yourself. I have a suspicion that paho is doing concurrency itself internally, which make creating your own threads supefluous.